# Trouble overriding the default limit in an Apigee GET request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Using Javascript, I'm trying to make an AJAX GET request with several search conditions to Apigee. I'm building the request language as a joined array, then running the result through the function encodeURIComponent().

For the life of me, can't figure out how to increase the default limit! No matter where I try appending the language, I'm always given just 10 results.

Here's one version of the function:

```
function getRange(flower, day) {
   var startRange = new Date();
   startRange.setDate(day);
   var endRange = new Date();
   endRange.setDate(startRange.getDate() + 1);

   var arr = [
      "'select where flowerType = ",
      '"', 
      flower, 
      '"', 
      " and created gte ",
      startRange.getTime(),
      " and created lte ",
      endRange.getTime(),
      " order by created asc",
      "'&limit=1000"]

   var searchParameters = arr.join('');
   return (encodeURIComponent(searchParameters));
}
```

This is all passed into another function that actually makes the AJAX request:

```
function getReport(flower, day) {
   $.ajax({
      "url": "http://api.usergrid.com [etc, etc] ?ql=" + getRange(flower, day),
      "type": "GET",
      "success": function(data) {
         console.log(data.entities.length);
         };
    });
}
```

I'd appreciate any suggestions. I've tried the language "limit:1000", "&limit:1000", and "&limit=1000" after each of the conditions in my GET request to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Apigee Documentation](http://apigee.com/docs/app-services/content/working-queries) limiting query should look like this:

```
/users?ql=select * where name = 'fred*'&limit=50
```

The problem is in your code. You should pass all params that need to be appended to url into ajax's `data` option:

```
function getRange(flower, day) {
    var startRange = new Date();
    startRange.setDate(day);
    var endRange = new Date();
    endRange.setDate(startRange.getDate() + 1);

    return {
        ql: "select where flowerType = '" 
            + flower + "' and created gte " 
            + startRange.getTime() + " and created lte " 
            + endRange.getTime() + " order by created asc",
        limit: 1000
    }
}

function getReport(flower, day) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://api.usergrid.com [etc, etc]",
        type: "GET",
        data: getRange(flower, day),

        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data.entities.length);
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions--However, I'm not sure the new language is actually parsing my Apigee entries with my intended parameters. Using the corrections you've suggested, I do more than the default 10 entities, but they don't fit my "flowerType" or "created" parameters. In fact, if I fire the getReport for every different flower, I get the exact same entities. When I used the encodeURIComponent() function in my original code above, it returned entities that fit my parameters, but only 10 of them.

Comment: Try using double quotes for query values instead of single ones and check sending request url in firebug or chrome web-dev tools

Comment: Indeed! Switching the quotes in the query values solved the problem. Your code worked, as did appending "&limit=1000" at the end of the "url" field in the GET request. For example--
 
"url": "http://api.usergrid.com [etc, etc] ?ql=" + getRange(flower, day) + "&limit=1000",